# TestCafe with Electron throwing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, testing, electron, automated-tests, testcafe

**Problem**

I am getting the following error in devtools when I run TestCafe with the testcafe-electron-browser-provider plugin and the test is stuck on "Loading Webpage".

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined`

Anyone seen this issue or know how it can be resolved?

**Environment:**

- electron: "9.3.2,"
- node: "12.18.2",
- testcafe: "1.9.4",
- testcafe-browser-provider-electron: "0.0.15"
- OS: Windows 10

**Screenshots:**

- [Screenshot - TestCafe with Electron Stuck on loading page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9iJn.png)
- [Screenshot - Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uekAN.png)

**Code Snippets**

*Error:*

```
backend.js:5206 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
at e (backend.js:5206)
at l (hammerhead.js:15)
at t.r._onWindowMessage (hammerhead.js:7)
at n (hammerhead.js:15)
at i (hammerhead.js:8)
at hammerhead.js:7
```

*My testcafe config file:*

```
module.exports = {
src: '/test/specs/e2etest.js',
mainWindowUrl: './build/index.html',
appPath: './',
};
```

*My e2etest.js file:*

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `TestCafe Electron Trial`
         .page('../../build/index.html');

test('check title', async (t) => {
    await t.expect(Selector('title').innerText).eql('Electron Application');
});

test.skip('open file menu open project', async (t) => {
    await t.click("[data-test-id='fileControls-fileMenu']");
    await t.click(Selector('span').withText('Open project'));
    await t.click("[data-test-id='openFileDialog-browse']");
});
```

Comment: I think its generated by the desktopCapturer module, not sure about why it happens

Answer (score 2):

Browser's Development Tools can cause errors when you use them during test execution. It's a known issue, and it is described at [TestCafe documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/run-tests.html).

Comment: Hi, Browser Development Tools was not open when this happened. I had also tried to disable the DevTools in electron.he and still had this issue.

Comment: This looks like a TestCafe problem. Please create an issue in the TestCafe repository and share a simple example to reproduce the problem.